# React Native: How to create "grid" layout using flexbox?

Tags: css, react-native, gridview, flexbox

I would want a 3xN layout on my mobile React Native app, so something like this:

```
[    ] [    ] [    ]    
title1 title2 title3    
                        
[    ] [    ] [    ]
title4 title5 title6

[    ] [    ] [    ]
title7 title8 title9

...    ...    ...
```

This entire layout, vertical wise, will be in a ScrollView so that even if it loads more items than 1 screen can present, it can show properly in it's entirety.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set `flexWrap: 'wrap'` on the container and, if you want a constant number of items per row, give your items a `flexBasis: '33%'` rather than a static value to ensure that the width scales properly for the device